# Identity first Stripe webhook for invoice.payment_succeeded

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

When I setup a subscription with Stripe, a webhook is triggered with the type "invoice.payment_succeeded".

Is there a way to identify whether or not this webhook is the first one?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first one"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the `event.request.id` property of the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event you receive.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-request-id

When an Event is triggered by an automatic renewal `event.request.id` will be `null`. When triggered by an API request (starting the subscription) the value of `event.request.id` will contain a request id (`req_xxyyyzzz`).